# Tascam DP 006 Stereo Recording

Tags: recording, stereo, tascam

I'm very new to multitrack recording and I'm stumped by something on my Tascam DP 006.

I have a left and right out of my loop station going into the A and B inputs on the DP 006 respectively.

When I have "monox2" selected on the input settings, I can hear both channels fine, but when I select "stereo", the right channel disappears from the mix. Instead I end up with the left channel coming though both sides of my headphones.

In terms of the display, in "monox2" mode on the input select page, the A and B levels are different, reflecting the source, but the L + R levels are the same. In "stereo" mode the levels for A and B and L + R are different, reflecting the relative levels of A and B, but I can only hear the left input, coming out of both sides of my headphones.

I want to record a stereo track on track 4, which is set to stereo, but when I record, only the version without the right input seems to get recorded (unless it's there and I'm not able to hear it for some reason).

This makes no sense at all to me. What am I missing please?

Comment: Do you put it in master play mode to play back the recording? I've just had a quick look at [the manual](https://www.tascam.eu/en/docs/DP-006_Manual.pdf).